# laravel 5.5 ban/deactivate user

Tags: php, laravel

in my code after creating a usermiddleware, calling it in routemiddleware and adding it to route, users banned still get access whenever they log in and I get no error, maybe I missed something. here is my code

my usermiddelware(did php artisan make: middleware UserMiddleware)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UserMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->activation_status)
        {
            $banned = Auth::user()->activation_status == "1";
            Auth::logout();

            if($banned == 1) {
                $message = 'Your account has been banned. please contacct Admin.';
            }
            return redirect()->route('login')
                ->with('status', $message)
                ->withErrors(['email' => 'Your email has been banned. please contacct Admin.']);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

kernel(added isuser at routemiddleware)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    ];

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'role' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole::class,
        'permission' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustPermission::class,
        'ability' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustAbility::class,
        'isUser' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserMiddleware::class,  
    ];
}
```

my route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','isUser']], function () {
 
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('dashboard');

});
```

Comment: What is the type of `activation_status` is it boolean, integer or something else ? and what is the value of active status is it 1 or 0 ?

Comment: activation_status is a tiny integer and value of active status is 0@mmabdelgawad

Comment: you could not let them login as well, you can have `attempt` check the status of that field

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler solution

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UserMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->activation_status)
        {
              return redirect()->route('login')
                  ->with('status', "Your account has been banned. please contact Admin.")
                  ->withErrors(['email' => 'Your email has been banned. please contact Admin.']);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and in your blade you will add something similar to

```
<span>{{ session('status) }}<span>
```

**Note** - it's better to make `activation_status` of type `boolean` and active will be `true` not `false`.

Comment: yea this inverse of true and false they are using seems a bit confusing ... if you send them to the `login` route you will end up getting redirected away since it has the `guest` middleware attached by default

Comment: did everything you but nothing yet, or my route is the issue?@mmabdelgawad

Comment: did you redirected to `login` route ? or didn't you seen the `status` message ? or what is the error ?